# Which determiner? -- "Please submit a photocopy of { a / the / your } residence card"

Tags: determiners

What is the correct question?

> Please submit a photocopy of [a / the / your] residence card

Comment: Please add more details. Like what is the situation? Is someone asking you to submit a copy of your card?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Please submit a photocopy of **a** residence card.

means: "Please submit a photocopy of **any** residence card." This could be your card or someone else's card. Depending on the context it might be a card of just any person on Earth, or a card belonging to a member of some particular group.

> 2. Please submit a photocopy of **the** residence card

means: "Please submit a photocopy of the residence card that has been previously mentioned, explicitly or implicitly." It could be your card, or someone else's card, depending on the context:

> Does your husband have a residence card? Press Yes or No.
>   (You press "Yes")
>   Please submit a photocopy of **the** residence card. (meaning: your husband's)
>   (You submit the photocopy)
>   Thank you. Do you have a residence card? Press Yes or No.
>   (You press "Yes")
>   Please submit a photocopy of **the** residence card. (meaning: your own residence card)

Now,

> 3. Please submit a photocopy of **your** residence card.

means what it says: the required photocopy is of **your** own residence card.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I am making a paper to ask foreign employees to submit documents for contracts. So, I guess "your residence card" will do the best.

Comment: I am making a paper to ask foreign employees to submit documents for contracts. So, I guess "your residence card" will do the best.

Comment: @kaobe - I guess it will do. I can come up with one situation when it might be awkward - if "**your** residence card" is mentioned repeatedly in closely situated sentences. In this case, it might be better to switch to **the** after the first use of **your** - but it all depends on the context, I'm afraid.